# There is no "Run on Server" option on eclipse to run the project on Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I have a maven project that wants to run on Tomcat 7; however, when I right click on the project name there is no option other than Java Applet, Java Application, JUnit Test, Maven related options and Run Configurations.

[image]

[image]

[image]
Please let me know if you need any further information that I should have provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this steps:

First of all make sure you have added Tomcat server in your eclipse. if it is not then first do that. 
then

Right Click on project => Run As => Run Configuration

Select Apache Server and select configured tomcat.

You are good to go now.

Comment: Just double click on Tomcat V7.0 server line from run configuration. It will pick that server configuration and start executing.

Comment: I double clicked on the server, it got started but project has not started, is it possible to add "Ran On Server" option?

Comment: make sure that Your project is imported as web project and in above comment I mean from run configuration double click on Tomcat v7.0 line. If your project is not imported as web project then you can't run it on server.